# What was a GuardedCatchClause in the SpiderMonkey parser?

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

The SpiderMonkey JavaScript engine's parser [once supported a nonterminal symbol `GuardedCatchClause`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=742612), which when parsed would produce entries in the `.guardedHandlers` property of the associated `TryStatement`; this property [also appeared in the ESTree spec at the time](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/835c958221d264578adb109b639478664b3b82a8/spec.md#trystatement).

Unfortunately I have not found any references to the syntax of `try` statements with `GuardedCatchClause`s on the web.  What was the actual syntax and semantics?  Were these essentially `catch` clauses with an additional `if`-like conditional?

Additionally: was GuardedCatchClause part of the ES4 proposals?  (I have never seen reference to this in any of the ES4 feature retrospectives I have read.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does refer to conditional `catch` clauses. You can find a description of them in the [web archive of the Mozilla documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20190829045039/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch):

> #### Conditional catch clauses
>
> > **Non-standard**
> > This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
> > track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
> > work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
> > implementations and the behavior may change in the future.
>
> You can also use one or more conditional `catch` clauses to handle
> specific exceptions. In this case, the appropriate `catch` clause is
> entered when the specified exception is thrown. In the following
> example, code in the `try` block can potentially throw three exceptions:
> `TypeError`, `RangeError`, and `EvalError`. When an exception occurs,
> control transfers to the appropriate `catch` clause. If the exception is
> not one of the specified exceptions and an unconditional `catch` clause
> is found, control transfers to that `catch` clause.
>
> If you use an unconditional `catch` clause with one or more conditional
> `catch` clauses, the unconditional `catch` clause must be specified last.
> Otherwise, the unconditional `catch` clause will intercept all types of
> exception before they can reach the conditional ones.
>
> Reminder: this functionality is not part of the ECMAScript
> specification and has been removed in Firefox 59. It's not supported
> in any current browser anymore.
>
> ```
> try {
>   myroutine(); // may throw three types of exceptions
> } catch (e if e instanceof TypeError) {
>   // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
> } catch (e if e instanceof RangeError) {
>   // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
> } catch (e if e instanceof EvalError) {
>   // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
> } catch (e) {
>   // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
>   logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
> }
> ```
>
> Here is the same "Conditional catch clauses" using code that conforms
> to ECMAScript specification (obviously it's verbose, but works
> everywhere):
>
> ```
> try {
>   myroutine(); // may throw three types of exceptions
> } catch (e) {
>   if (e instanceof TypeError) {
>     // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
>   } else if (e instanceof RangeError) {
>     // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
>   } else if (e instanceof EvalError) {
>     // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
>   } else {
>     // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
>     logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
>   }
> }
> ```

As noted, [they were removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1228841) from Firefox [in version 59 (March 13, 2018)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/59#javascript_2)